# How to open a weblink through php

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3

I have been trying to get my <kbd>Raspberry Pi 3</kbd> Server to open a Website through either `Epiphany` or `Chromium` via `PHP`.

This <kbd>Pi</kbd> acts as an alarm clock that will play music over a `webstream` when the alarm goes off.

I know a script is necessary, because simply writing `exec('epiphany www.examplewebsite.com');` won't do anything.

So my question is, **what is the smartest and easiest way to approach this problem?**

```html
?php
$hour = $_GET["hour"];
$mins = $_GET["mins"];


// this basically controls GPIO pins but I want it to open a Website or do other stuff

//exec('echo "'.$mins.' '.$hour.' * * * sudo gpio -g write 18 1; sudo /home/pi/raspberry-remote/./send 11010 1 1" | crontab -'); ?>
```

Comment: `file_get_contents` or `curl` will get you the content of a website. Depending on that webpage does though that may or may not work.

Comment: This didn't work for me. All I need to do is start an application through php.

Comment: So the question is not `how to open a weblink through php`. Edit the question as needed.